# 現在開いているブラウザタブを、色々な条件で並び替えることができるChrome拡張を探しているのですが

Tags: chrome-extension

**最終的にやりたいこと**
・Chromeブラウザでaツイートを開く
・新しいタブでbツイートを開く
・この時、各ツイートの投稿日時昇順でタブを並べ替えるChrome拡張を作りたい

**これまでに試したこと**
検索してみたら、[TabJuggler](https://www.gigafree.net/internet/googlechrome/TabJuggler.html)が見つかったので、下記コード部分を、取得した投稿日時のDOMでソートするよう変更しようと思ったのですが、古いためかコードが見つかりません。

> 現在開いているタブを、タイトル / ホスト名 / URL 順　に並べ替えたり

**Q.現在開いているブラウザタブを、色々な条件で並び替えることができるChrome拡張はありますか？**

Comment: プロジェクトとしてはこんなのがあるようですが違う物あるいは不完全なのでしょうか？ [lucabelluccini/tabjuggler](https://github.com/lucabelluccini/tabjuggler), [tabjuggler](https://code.google.com/archive/p/tabjuggler/) 他にTabSorterとかで検索するとこんなのがあるようですが。[pwhite2/simple-tab-sorter](https://github.com/pwhite2/simple-tab-sorter), [Nonj/TabSorter](https://github.com/Nonj/TabSorter), [Re-sorting Web-based Tabs like it works in Google Chrome](https://itnext.io/re-sorting-web-based-tabs-like-it-works-in-google-chrome-38d749fc8ede)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。

Comment: 別の方向性で、標準機能のタブのグループ分けを使っています。複数のタブを開くのは何らかの目的を持ったテーマがあるはずで、そのテーマごとにグループ化し、不要なグループは最小化してます。